# In python if a instance data attribute has the same name as the class data attribute, then can we access both for such an object

Tags: python

I have the following code in python

```
class C :
    attr = 'class attr'
    def f1(self) :
        attr = '10' # local scope
        self.attr = 'obj attr'

print C.attr
obj = C()

obj.f1()
print C.attr
print obj.attr, obj.__class__.__dict__['attr']
```

Thus I can have an instance attribute with the same name as the class attribute and accessing such an attribute normally accesses the instance attribute.

I just started learning python, so please let me know if this understanding of mine is in place.
And I want to know that if I have to access such a class attribute then is there some other way of doing so - other than what I have done in the code.

Comment: What's the result you've found so far? Your last line of code should answer your question, I'd think.

Comment: No need to access `__dict__`: you can just use `obj.__class__.attr`.

Comment: I understand, thank you @Andrea Corbellini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you understood correctly.

Python first looks for the attribute in the instance and, if it's not found there, it looks in the class (and base classes...). For example consider:

```
class Foo:
     x = 42

f = Foo()
g = Foo()

g.x = 99

print(f.x, g.x)
```

will show you that `f` is accessing `42` while `g` is accessing `99`.

To access the class attribute even if there is an instance attribute with the same name you can use either

- `Foo.x`
- `getattr(Foo, 'x')`
- `Foo.__dict__['x']`

because in Python classes are regular object instances too

Comment: Thanks, Also I want to know if there is any other way of accessing this hidden class attribute other than the one that I am using in the code